# "Your job is more easy than mine" – is the comparative formed properly?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-degrees, gradable-adjectives

This [post](http://www.whichenglish.com/Better-English-Grammar/usage/easier-or-more-easily.html) talks about the difference between *easier* and *more easily*, which inspired me another expression

> Your job is more easy than mine

is this a proper expression? I guess it is grammatical but not a normal expression. so I need a double confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct-- it is grammatical but not idiomatic in this context. You would more likely say "your job is easier than mine". Although maybe don't actually say that to someone unless you want to get punched. ;)

Comment: *More easy* is not grammatically correct.

Comment: @Charles I'm not a grammarian so I'm willing to be wrong about this, but I think "more easy" is grammatical. It's an awkward construction in writing without any modifier (because "easier" is more appropriate) but certainly in speech with the right inflection "more easy" would pass absolutely unnoticed, which suggests to me that it's grammatical. (Imagine saying: "Is your job *less* easy than mine? Absolutely not! Your job is MORE easy!")

Comment: "Is your job *easier* than mine?" ... "Absolutely not! Your job is *easier*." In both cases, *easier* is the proper adjective to use.

Comment: In neither case should *more easy* be used. However, if you were to say, "your job is *more/less difficult* than mine", then that would be correct.

Comment: I really don’t believe it’s incorrect or ungrammatic to say more easy, more fast, more happy, more red, even though we have established comparative forms for those adjectives. I’m willing to bet a great many English speakers would find “more fast” particularly unidiomatic; it strikes me as even clumsier than “more easy”. As for the colour adjectives I think you’ll hear both forms widely. There are adjectives classed as absolutes which we’re told mustn’t be compared (“unique” the common example) but for a comparable one, I think it’s technically legal to use “more” if you want.